# Serve fifo over http

Tags: http, debian, fifo

I got a fifo file... created on Debian with command `mkfifo stream.500` ... I can serve it directly via TCP with command `cat stream.500 | nc -l 12345` ... but the problem is that nc closes connection after first client disconnect and it doesn't serve proper HTTP response...

What I need is the same as above, but so I would be able to serve it as HTTP response.

I tried to serve that fifo file over HTTP with Apache, but Apache seems to stuck reading it and breaks fifo pipe on try.

Any ideas?

PS. Fifo file contains video stream.

Comment: Who writes to the FIFO? The problem is that most likely there are no active writers after the first request so `read(2)` returns 0 and `cat` terminates.

Comment: raspivid writes fifo... and it works as VLC can open it...

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: no, sorry... I mean probably media streaming server would work, but I didn't have time nor resources to install it, so I dropped the project